# What are the rights of the font "Marcelle"?

Tags: font-licensing

I found this amazing font that i want to use for my application. It is called "Marcelle" and it's available on almost any font website. Some say it's free, others say it's "free for personal use". Since i want to use this font commercially, is there any way for me to buy it, or can i just go ahead and use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tiniest bit of research (Google > Dafont > Sterotype) finds......

From the foundry's (StereoType) web site.....

[image: License]

Send the folks a donation.